# How to show Trigger error in a salesforce flow

Tags: visual-workflow

Getting the following error in flow: An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow
An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information.

Want to show actual trigger error (addError)in flow.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Rather than just ditch the error from the trigger, validation message or whatever, you can use the flow to capture and present the error message nicely as covered in my answer to the above question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Phil W.  
Now I have an error screen but it's not a user-friendly error message. it's showing in the following way:       

The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION: Please add primary internal SDM in Project Team. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

I just want to show the error message that is "Please add primary internal SDM in Project Team"

Comment: Got it Phil. showing condition-based error screen and in the condition checkin the error message in faultMassage. Thanks